# nginx as https proxy, but want to intercept one static path for Let's Encrypt /.well-known challenges

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

There is lots of material about using ngix as a reverse proxy and it is working well for me as a basic proxy for a strange web server app I need to use.  I even have redirect on so http gets redirected to https.

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    <my server>;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen         443 ssl;
    server_name    <my server>;


    # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate cert1.crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key cert1.key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81; # my existing apache instance
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

Now I have one new wrinkle.  I'd like to pick off one particular path and NOT have it get forwarded to the main server app.  I need to do this to add in some Let's Encrypt challenge responses.  Whenever the incoming url is http:///.well-known/acme-challenge/ then I want to use a static nginx path and NOT fwd to the main server.

Any ideas?  I tried adding in a location directory but that wasn't working.

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    video.maritimeopscorp.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen         443 ssl;
    server_name    video.maritimeopscorp.com;


    # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate cert1.crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key cert1.key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    location ~ /.well-known {
      <I've tried lots of combinations here.>
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81; # my existing apache instance
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

I'd also prefer to get this up into the 80 block rather than the 443 block but little steps first.

Any ideas?

Comment: The ACME challenge requests to `/.well-known/acme-challenge` are done on port 80 over plain HTTP, not over HTTPS on port 443.

Comment: That was my final point about getting into the 80 block rather than the 443 but I can't get it to work under either yet.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, verify the server with certbot and store the SSL certificate locally?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [`root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root), to inform `nginx` where the `.well-known` directory can be found:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    video.maritimeopscorp.com;
    location / {
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known {
        root /path/to/enclosing/directory;
    }
}
```

Enclose the `return` statement inside the default [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), otherwise it will always take precedence.